# Recover lost C2DM Registration ID?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

We've got the basics of C2DM registration and communication down.  Nice job Google!!

I'm wondering what we can do if we have successfully registered a device that has to be wiped for some reason.  We've now lost all saved information for our app, but is there a way we can ask Google to send us our old registration ID.  If there is then could use it to query our servers and identify the user there without forcing them to authenticate themselves again.

Thanks,
-Ken

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving the registration ID to your third party server. Otherwise, if you've just saved it to the SharedPreferences and, as you mentioned, wiped the device/app then the registration id is gone.

Comment: The registration ID is saved on the third party server of course.  That is how the can message our app on different devices.  And a user who has had their phone wiped can always log in to the server, authenticate themselves, and then request that the server send the registration ID back to the phone.

Comment: But I'm thinking if that Google's servers must have the registration ID and know it is attached to this phone.  If we can get them to send it to us, our app can go ahead and query the third party server with the registration ID and re-establish the account connection without any user interaction whatsoever.

It doesn't help that the third party server isn't "our" server.  It belongs to one of several third parties that we give permission to message our app.